# Simple swapExactInputSingle from Uniswap V3 fails on Rinkeby

Tags: ethereum, solidity, uniswap

I've tried to follow [Uniswaps guide](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/single-swaps) for implementing simple `swapExactInputSingle` function and deployed the contract on Rinkeby.

Code:

```
contract Swap {
    using LowGasSafeMath for uint256;

    address private constant SWAP_ROUTER =
        0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564;
    address private constant WETH = 0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab;
    address public constant DAI = 0xc7AD46e0b8a400Bb3C915120d284AafbA8fc4735;

    address public immutable _owner;
    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;

    constructor() {
        _owner = msg.sender;
        swapRouter = ISwapRouter(SWAP_ROUTER);
    }

    function swapExactInputSingle(uint256 amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint256 amountOut)
    {
        //Transfer DAI here, and approve its usage for router
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            DAI,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountIn
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: DAI,
                tokenOut: WETH,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

DAI and WETH addresses seems to be correct for the Rinkeby network. I've tried with both of Uniswap SwapRouters addresses (I'm not sure which I should use: `SwapRouter` or `SwapRouter02` from [their doc](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments)), changing them didn't influce the result. After deploying the contract, when I try to interact with it through etherscan with use of MetaMask, in the metamask before confirming the transaction I get a warning:

`This transaction is expected to fail. Trying to execute it is expected to be expensive but fail, and is not recommended.`

After confirming this transaction it takes really long time and eventually, it does indeed fail.

What am I doing wrong? I do have correct DAI in my Wallet

Also, why MetaMask for my transaction suggests gas limit of `28472169` and when I'm interacting with Uniswap V3 interface, for the same swap it suggests only `129129` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned our there were 2 separate problems.

First one, was the thing mentioned by @Crypto_Rachel. The approval inside contract was only one of the two needed approvals. Before the trade, we also needed to manually approve OUR contract to get the token (DAI) from our wallet.

As I mentioned in the question, I've been trying two different swap routers:
`SwapRouter` and `SwapRouter02`. After the first issue has been fixed, I've kept testing using only `SwapRouter02`.

It turned out, that `SwapRouter02` uses different `ExactInputSingleParams` struct. It does not have `delay` parameter. With my usage of `import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol"` and the struct it provided I should have used `SwapRouter`. Switching to that router resolved an issue and made my transaction pass.

If you want to read about that in details check this blogpost:
https://brightinventions.pl/blog/single-swap-on-uniswap-v3-with-3-common-mistakes

Answer (score 1):

make sure you approve your contract to spend your dai from your wallet

```
//Transfer DAI here, and approve its usage for router
    TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
        DAI,
        msg.sender,
        address(this),
        amountIn
    );
```

This function transfers the dai from your wallet to your contract
and it needs the approval
manually approve your contract to spend the dai in your wallet via its contract or abi
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc7ad46e0b8a400bb3c915120d284aafba8fc4735#writeContract

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed this seems to be a part of the issue. I no longer have 
`Fail with error 'TransferHelper::transferFrom: transferFrom failed'`
error after sending a transaction but some other issue still occurs. After approving DAI transfer, MetaMask still warns that the transaction will fail and indeed it does without no additional message. 
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x0860082f6617f05a103356bac3bc445216b2220f0c725b0e1593ac7b98eb1dff